# How to set TIME_OUT on async class android

Tags: android, performance

**Here's my layout code;**

```
   private class mainAdapter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String response = "";
          for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }

            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(flagsearch)
            {   
                pd.dismiss();
                if(result.trim().contains("Result not found !"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    String limit=""+0;
                    Intent i= new Intent(Main_Search.this,Main_listview.class);
                    i.putExtra("line", result);
                    i.putExtra("limit",0);
                    i.putExtra("Alert", false);
                    i.putExtra("str_Descrption",str_desc);
                    i.putExtra("str_location", str_location);
                    startActivity(i);   
                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
                edit_location.setText(result);      
            str_location= edit_location.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {
            if(flagsearch)
            {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(Main_Search.this, "","Please wait...");
            }

        }
      }
```

I am calling asyn class on main thred

```
mainAdapter mm= new mainAdapter();
                String    url="http://www.jobdiagnosis.com/servicesearch.php?keyword="+str_desc+
                        "&location="+str_location;
                url= url.replace(" ","%20");
                mm.execute(url);
```

Program is working fine but some site fetching data from server take a much time then i want to set time_out but i don't have any idea to set Time_out

Plz Help me for using TIME_OUT and also suggast me why fetching data take a time?

I am really sorry for my bad english.

Comment: please review the accepted answer again as it has been taken away from my answer to a spam answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in the `doInBackground` in the `AsyncTask`

```
int socket_timeout = 3000;
int connection_timeout = 3000;
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, connection_timeout);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, socket_timeout);
DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Answer (score 2):

One efficient way is to call AsyncTask within a handler and cancel it after a given timeout with postDelayed.

In your activity you would have

```
private void readFromServer(String url, int timeout)
{
    // read from server
    final ServerHit serverHit = new ServerHit ();
    serverHit.execute(url);
    // set a timeout
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (serverHit.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                serverHit.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }, timeout);
}
```

ServerHit is a subclass of AsyncTask

Comment: great it's very useful..